# Specify device family in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

Is there a way to specify the device family solely based on a key in Info.plist, without changing the build settings?
I have read about UIDeviceFamily being added automatically to Info.plist at build time, and the documentation says that I should not add this key manually. 
Let's say I cannot use Xcode, but I can edit Info.plist, is there a way to specify if the app should be running only on iPhone (or iPad)?

Thank you,

Answer (score 10):

check out the docs in UIDeviceFamily

[UIDeviceFamily](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11)

if you need to only support ipad, set the DeviceFamily to 2.
For iphone set to 1.
For universe include both 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you should not add UIDeviceFamily in Info.plist.
However, if you are generating bulid from commandline, you can set TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY, "1" for iPhone and "2" for iPad:

```
xcodebuild \
  -target "${TARGET}" \
  -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="2"
```