# Nativescript Apple app store Iphone only

Tags: ios, nativescript

Hello guys I have a quick question
Im building my app with Nativescript, but
When I upload my app to Apple for the review i always have to provide screenshot of this app running on an iPad. So i guess somewhere is some property file you can specify for what default device for App is.

How can I set this ??
In info.plist or some other file ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose between three options when creating an iOS app, either **iPhone**,  **iPad** or **Universal**. An iPhone app does not mean that it cannot run on iPad though, it just means that isn't optimized for it.

The property that needs to be changed is called `UIDeviceFamily`, but is added to `Info.plist` by Xcode, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075311/specify-device-family-in-info-plist) and [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10) this property is set automatically and should thus not be added manually, so I am not sure how to do this with NativeScript. There is also an [unanswered thread on the NativeScript Discourse](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-specify-that-i-want-the-app-to-support-iphone-only-and-not-ipad-so-no-universal/1461) that deals with the same problem and mentions that setting it in the `App_Resources/ios/Info.plist` does not work.

A word of caution though, once you release an Universal app, you cannot go back to an iPhone only app, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055402/switch-universal-app-to-iphone-only-app).

Comment: NativeScript Sidekick add `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1;` to `build.xcconfig` and it works!